# geolocalización entre dispositivos (Unity)

Tags: geolocalización, unity

Estoy haciendo en Unity 2 apps, una que obtenga datos de geolocalización (coodenadas gps) y otra que reciba esos datos y los muestre en un mapa. La aplicación en sí es para rastreo de dispositivos para verificar que no salgan del límite permitido.

Ahora bien, no tengo idea de algún servicio o como enviar los datos del dispositivo emisor al receptor (pueden estar a cientos o miles de kms de distancia). Si pudiera ayudarme a darme ideas se los agradecería

Comment: debes tener un servidor que mantenga las direcciones de los dispositivos para que estos se conecten entre si, o que el mismo servidor mantenga esta información disponible para que las aplicaciones la obtengan cuando se conecten a internet, de todas formas esta pregunta es demasiada amplia para este sitio :(

Comment: Utiliza una base de datos en un server. Puedes usar [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpOid2Obd2AIVSyrTCh3JFAXREAAYASAAEgIVO_D_BwE), por ejemplo. La app 1 sube los datos y la app 2 los lee.

Comment: Para compartir datos debes usar servicios web: Opcion 1:
unitymultiplayer: si debes compartir y procesar los datos en tiempo real es excelente, ademas todo su codigo queda escrito en C#, Pero tiene ciertas limitaciones como un maximo de 20 usuarios activos a la vez de manera gratuita. Opcion 2:
Firebase: para solo compartir los datos es muy buena pero no permite procesarlos, debes procesarlos de manera local en tu app, Firebase si puede procesar datos pero puede tardar 5s por peticion porque lo hace de manera asincrona. Los limites gratuitos son altos. Creo que maximo 100 usuarios y hasta 10gb

Comment: Gracias por responder! esta es una pregunta muy vieja y puede que no recibas nada por parte de quien pregunto. Igual te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [answer].

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias, este proyecto quedó inconcluso, pero tal vez en un futuro me pueda ser de utilidad tu aporte, gracias!